# How do I shutdown Spring GRACEFULLY AND close all mysql connections with a HTML button?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Im working on a SpringBoot project.
Everytime I have to stop spring and start again, more connections are used to 'connect' to the mysql database. Recently I had issues with max-connections so I made a code that shutsdown spring and release all connections after I click on it. However, Spring gives me an exception and nothing is shown on the screen to inform me that the shutdown process worked. I understand why no message is shown: Its because spring is shutdown before the message is sent.

Im stuck with this situation. It works, but its not perfect. It gives an exception and no information is showing to me. How can I improve this?
PS: I use Apache Netbeans 12.1 from https://netbeans.apache.org/

This is the HTML with the button to call the method that shuts everything down.

```
<div class="panel-body col-md-12">

                <form action="#" th:action="@{'/shutdown'}" th:method="shutdown" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="shutdownPost" />
                    <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Shutdown </button>
                </form>

            </div>
```

This is my RestController that I use to shutdown Spring and close all the Hikari Connections to the MYSQL database.

```
package br.winter.controller;

import br.winter.AnaccaratiPlatformApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ShutDown {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/shutdown", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String shutdown() {
        return dispose();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/shutdown", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String shutdownPost() {

        return dispose();
    }

    private String dispose() {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = AnaccaratiPlatformApplication.getRun();
        String result = "";
        try {
            context.stop();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            result = result + ex.getMessage();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            context.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            result = result + "<br>" + ex.getMessage();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        result = result + "<br><br>" + "Shutdown complete!!";

        return result;
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
2020-11-28 17:19:00.299  INFO 6304 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-11-28 17:19:00.301  INFO 6304 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper   : Waiting for [1] instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [dispatcherServlet]
2020-11-28 17:19:01.397  INFO 6304 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper   : Waiting for [1] instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [dispatcherServlet]
2020-11-28 17:19:02.498  INFO 6304 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper   : Waiting for [1] instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [dispatcherServlet]
2020-11-28 17:19:02.608  INFO 6304 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-11-28 17:19:02.629  WARN 6304 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Cannot serialize session attribute [SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT] for session [173291AEDABC313B17952E184CCFD485]

java.io.NotSerializableException: br.Winter.model.login.Tunnel
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.doWriteObject(StandardSession.java:1702) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1057) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:315) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:267) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stopInternal(StandardManager.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5429) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1389) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:976) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1389) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:976) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:473) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:992) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:496) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stopTomcat(TomcatWebServer.java:273) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stop(TomcatWebServer.java:331) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.stop(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:51) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.SmartLifecycle.stop(SmartLifecycle.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:238) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$300(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.stop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:377) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.stopBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.stop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:116) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.stop(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1370) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at br.Winter.controller.ShutDown.dispose(ShutDown.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at br.Winter.controller.ShutDown.shutdownPost(ShutDown.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:155) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:52) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:216) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:141) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2020-11-28 17:19:02.673  WARN 6304 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : The executor associated with thread pool [http-nio-8080] has not fully shutdown. Some application threads may still be running.
2020-11-28 17:19:02.677  INFO 6304 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-11-28 17:19:02.678  INFO 6304 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-11-28 17:19:02.679  INFO 6304 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-11-28 17:19:02.679  INFO 6304 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-11-28 17:19:02.685  INFO 6304 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Shutdown completed.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  31.708 s
Finished at: 2020-11-28T17:19:03-02:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project demo: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

---

Thanks for the reply.
Yes, im already using Hikari Pool. Here's the settings:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=2
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
```

However, the issue remains. When I close spring, the connections remain active for a period of time. I cant have that happening.

---

### Edit

In My application, I use two datasources. In My understanding, they are Singletons. So, am I supposed to just autowire them in my Shutdown class and use them to disconnect?

Calling `getConnection()` wont just create a new connection and so, when I call close on it, its just closing the same connection I just created?

PS: Am I supposed to not use Hikari?

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "loginDataSource")
    public DataSource loginDataSource(Environment env) {
        String url = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.url");
        String classname = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name");

        String username = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username");
        String password = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password");

        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .driverClassName(classname)
                .username(username)
                .password(password)
                .url(url)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "companyDependentDataSource")
    public DataSource companyDependentDataSource(Environment env) {
        return new UserSchemaAwareRoutingDataSource(); // Autowiring is done afterwards by Spring
    }
}
```

Comment: Clean up the resources in a `@PreDestroy`-annotated method.  Ideally this would be in the classes where the resources are initialized but you didn't say how you're getting the connections so you may have to annotate a method in another Spring-managed component.  See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Hikari.

I am guessing you are using the out of the box spring-boot defaults?

The default maximumPoolSize is 10:

maximumPoolSize
This property controls the maximum size that the pool is allowed to reach, including both idle and in-use connections. Basically this value will determine the maximum number of actual connections to the database backend. A reasonable value for this is best determined by your execution environment. When the pool reaches this size, and no idle connections are available, calls to getConnection() will block for up to connectionTimeout milliseconds before timing out. Please read about pool sizing. Default: 10

See if you can fine tune it to fit your needs best.   I honestly dont recommend you shutdown Springboot.

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby

================= Edited ==============

I can explain the reason the connections stay to the database for a long time after you shutdown.

Its because you are not shuting down appropriately.  Spring-Boot is not closing the connections towards the database, that is why you see them still.

I really suggest you increase your maximumPoolSize to something more than 10, and dont use a shutdown method.

If you MUST use a shutdown, then you need to do it cleanly by getting the Connection instance and doing connection.close();

```
private static HikariDataSource ds;

Connection con = ds.getConnection();
con.close();
```

close()
Releases this Connection object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for them to be automatically released.

============ Edited 2 =============

```
@RestController
public class ShutDown {


   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("loginDataSource")
   public DataSource loginDataSource;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/shutdown", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String shutdown() {
        return loginDataSource.getConnection().close();
    }

}
```

Comment: "If you MUST use a shutdown, then you need to do it cleanly by getting the Connection instance and doing connection.close();" How ??

Comment: I modified my answer to show you how to obtain a connection from your datasource, then call close on that connection @SHASHA

Comment: Im modifying my question one last time, Im a bit confused on how to work with the datasources I create. If you can help me with that, Thats all I need

Comment: @SHASHA I modified my answer, hope that is helpful.